# AngularJS - validation of dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say, we have an object like:

```
$scope.company = { name: { de: '', en: '' } };
```

and an input field saying:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="company.name[currentLanguage]" />
<button ng-click="currentLanguage='de'">Deutsch</button>
<button ng-click="currentLanguage='en'">English</button>
```

If the user fills in this field, the field receives the **ng-valid** class. If the user then changes the language (**$scope.currentLanguage** in fact), the input field is correctly updated (gets empty), but it has still the **ng-valid** class, which is wrong. The expected behavior would be rather **ng-pristine**. How to update this in real time?

Would be great to know that. 
Cheers

PS. There isn't any more code. That's just it.
PS2. It is another Problem as you suggest in the duplicate thread. I do not use ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you provide more code on where you are setting the class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate inputs dynamically created using ng-repeat, ng-show (angular)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044277/how-to-validate-inputs-dynamically-created-using-ng-repeat-ng-show-angular)

Comment: no duplicate. It is another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an input's value is changed in any way, it doesn't reset to **ng-pristine** unless you force it to.

You could manage the classes in your controller like so:

```
$scope.currentLanguage = 'de';
$scope.company = { name: { de: '', en: '' } };

$scope.setCurrentLanguage = function(str) {
$scope.currentLanguage = str;
var input = angular.element(document).find('input')[0];
if ($scope.company.name[str] == '') {
    angular.element(input).removeClass('ng-dirty');
    angular.element(input).removeClass('ng-invalid');
    angular.element(input).addClass('ng-pristine');
} else {
    angular.element(input).removeClass('ng-pristine');
    angular.element(input).addClass('ng-dirty');
}
}
```

and in the html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="company.name[currentLanguage]" />
<button ng-click="setCurrentLanguage('de')">Deutsch</button>
<button ng-click="setCurrentLanguage('en')">English</button>
```