# AngularJs radio buttons are connected when using ng-form with ng-repeat

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

See this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WZHMuYY3y2wbI6UysvY6?p=preview

When using a ng-form tag on an ng-repeat which contains a radio button group, the radio buttons are linked so if you check a radio button in one ng-repeat it will deselect in all the other ng-repeats. This puzzles me as the model of the ng-repeat is otherwise isolated from the other items. This is not only an issue when using ng-repeat. It also occurs when having multiple instances of a custom directive with isolated scope which renders a

```
<div ng-form name="myForm">
```

In the Plnkkr try adding a number of items and check the radio buttons on some of the items. 
They should be independent, but they are not.

Is this a bug in Angular? 
If not why does it work this way and how can I work around it?

```
<form name="mainForm" ng-submit="submitAll()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="subForm">          
          <input type="text" required name="name" ng-model="item.name"/>
          <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="r1" ng-model="item.radio" /> r1
          <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="r2" ng-model="item.radio" /> r2
          <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required">required</span>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="subForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitOne(item)">Submit One</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="mainForm.$invalid">Submit All</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those radio buttons are "connected" by a browser since you are giving them the same name. Just drop the `name` attribute and things start to work as expected:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AEtGstSBV6oydtvds52Y?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my problem for now. But suppose I marked the radio buttons as required and wanted to do <p ng-show="subForm.myRadio.$error">Some error</p>

Comment: Did you find a work around when you need a name attribute on the form input to allow the usual kind of behaviour with things like form.inputName.$error and form.inputName.$touched  ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your last comment, I have tried this out and it works. I'm not using the built-in angular validation but I believe it works all the same and is very simple

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="subForm">
      <input type="text" required name="name" ng-model="item.name"/>
      <input type="radio" value="r1" ng-model="item.radio" /> r1
      <input type="radio" value="r2" ng-model="item.radio" /> r2
      <span ng-show="item.radio==''">required</span>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="subForm.$invalid || item.radio==''" ng-click="submitOne(item) ">Submit One</button>
    </li>
```

See my working example at http://wiredbeast.com/coolframework/stackover.html

The trick is using `ng-show="item.radio==''"` to show the validation error and to disable the "Submit One" button.

In my honest opinion angular form validation  and browser validation with checkboxes and radios is not very solid.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I am not sure it works with dynamic names for validation. I think that is one of the reasons for using nested ng-forms.

Comment: Yes you're right it was not working. My bad, check out my edit though, this one I've tested.