# angular ngRepeat $index in name attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="fod in form.order_details">
...
    <td class="control-cell">
        <span ng-class="{error: prForm['qty_'+$index].$error.required && showValidationMessages}">
            <input type="number" name="{{'qty_' + $index}}" ng-model="fod.qty" ng-change="qtyPerKindCalc($index);" id="{{'qty_' + $index}}" required />
            <span ng-show="prForm['qty_'+$index].$error.required && showValidationMessages" class="error-msg">This field required</span>
        </span>
    </td>
...
</div>
```

ngRepeat, where i'm have required field. I'm have form object $scope.prForm - where i'm see $error. Problem is in name="{{'qty_' + $index}}". In $scope.prForm i'm have field

```
{{'qty_' + $index}}: instantiate.c
```

but i'm need

```
qty_0: instantiate.c
```

How I can have good {{'qty_' + $index}} operation in name attribute?

Comment: `name="qty_{{$index}}"` ?

Comment: Solution with dynamically names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12044600/1005180

Answer (score 9):

Very easy:

```
name="qty_{{$index}}"
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SP3Y81N9dULRZDsOBtV) to see how it work.

Comment: then i'm have qty_{{$index}}: instantiate.c, but i'm need qty_0: instantiate.c

i'm use AngularJS v1.2.9

Comment: Both your initial solution and this gives `qty_0`. Check your data-binding.

Comment: I am also in difficulty. Don't see problems. Just {{$index}} in name give me string '{{$index}}' - not '0' or '1' ...
in my example ng-change="qtyPerKindCalc($index);" transmits to the function good $index, i.e. 0 or 1 ..., but in name i'm have string '{{$index}}'

Comment: @user1005180, I put a link to plnkr so that you can see this approach work like a charm.

Comment: If i'm print in console $scope.prForm i'm have

    `instantiate.c {
        $error: Object,
        $name: "prForm",
        ....
        company: instantiate.c,
        job_name: instantiate.c,
        qty_{{$index}}: instantiate.c,
        __proto__: Ic`

Comment: Thanks - yes - it's works, but how i'm can to do validation in this case? If in form object i'm have field like: qty_{{$index}}: instantiate.c

Comment: [This doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) may be usefull for you. You can use binary $valid/$invalid to check validity. For form - use `prForm.$valid`, same for fields - `prForm.qty_0.$valid`.

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4yeLiVDlA9XbNuXdbpKh?p=preview)
Pls, see what i'm mean.

Comment: Yes, but in prForm i'm don't have qty_0, i'm have $qty_{{$index}}, then i'm can't to do check

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
id="qty_{{$index}}"
```

:)