# ng-class evaluation with ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add red frame to a field in a form in angular.
When working with static fields (not populated with `ng-repeat`) everything is working good. When the field is created with `ng-repeat` looks like the `ng-class` that uses the current index is not working. The form state is correct but the class with the red frame is not added to the field.

See this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hDfTHY?p=preview 
When adding a value to all input fields the button become enabled. However, only first input is red when empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add inner form:

```
<div ng-form="nested" class="col-md-4" ng-class="{'has-error': nested.item.$invalid}">
     <input type="text"
            ng-model="item"
            class="form-control"
            name="item"
            id="item{{$index}}"
            required ng-minlength="2">
</div>
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044277/how-to-validate-inputs-dynamically-created-using-ng-repeat-ng-show-angular)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work on the Plunker i created. Can you make it work on the Plunker please