# Validating repeating inputs inside an AngularJS form

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know this has been asked before, and have even found a well-upvoted answer here:

[How to validate inputs dynamically created using ng-repeat, ng-show (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044277/how-to-validate-inputs-dynamically-created-using-ng-repeat-ng-show-angular)

But I can't get that solution to work. I've got an example here - annoyingly both jsFiddle and Plunkr seem to be down right now.

Here's the JS:

```
app.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.formData = {
        lines: [{
            text: 'test.com'}]
    };
    $scope.addRow = function() {
      $scope.formData.lines.push({text:null});

    };
}]);
```

Here's the markup:

```
<body ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">
  <div>
    <form name="mainForm" novalidate class="form-vertical">
...some non-repeating inputs go in here...
      <div data-ng-repeat="line in formData.lines" data-ng-form="lineForm">

          <input type="text" name="myinput" data-ng-model="line.text" data-ng-required="true">
          <span data-ng-show="mainForm.lineForm.myinput.$error.required">Error!</span>


      </div>

      <a href='#' data-ng-click="addRow()">New Line</a>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>
```

You'll notice initially there is one text input with text in - great. Click the 'New Line' link. Because the new text input fails validation - BOTH text inputs get the warning span shown... I just want the one span relating to the one empty text input to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AngularJS relays on input names to expose validation errors, and you used the same name for all inputs, you faced with this effect.

So you can't generate input name dynamically, but instead you can use ng-form (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

```
<form name="mainForm" novalidate class="form-vertical">...some non-repeating inputs go in here...
    <div data-ng-repeat="line in formData.lines" data-ng-form="lineForm">
        <input type="text" name="myinput" data-ng-model="line.text" data-ng-required="true"> 
        <span data-ng-show="lineForm.myinput.$error.required">Error!</span>    
    </div> <a href='#' data-ng-click="addRow()">New Line</a>

</form>
```

**EDIT**. Please note, access to error `myinput.$error.required` instead of `lineForm.myinput.$error.required`.

Please, checkout working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/7/.

Comment: Sadly, jsFiddle still isn't working for me, so can't check... but did you notice I already have an inner ng-form - on the data-ng-repeat div I also have a data-ng-form directive. Also, I can't see any reference to your new innerForm in the data-ng-show expression, so are you sure this works?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: So, I updated fiddle and code in answer to working one. The point is in a way of accessing to error: instead of `mainForm.lineForm.myinput.$error.required` use `lineForm.myinput.$error.required`

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure I tried dropping the parent form from the ng-show expression before, but just tried it again and it worked now - great, thanks!

Comment: Good luck with Angular!