# accessing ng-form elements/values with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for the best way to pass non-binding (correct term?) form data to a controller method. How would I go about accessing the object of the form and it's values?

**html**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
<ng-form name="add_lead_form">
    <div ng-repeat="label in form.lead_labels track by $index" ng-show="label.visible">
        <div class="input-group lead-data">
            <span class="input-group-addon">{{getLabel(label)}}</span>
             <input ng-model="add_lead_form.addleadValue[$index]" name="addleadValue" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
             <input type="hidden" ng-model="add_lead_form.addleadLabelId[$index]" name="add_lead_form.addleadLabelId" ng-value="label.id" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="pull-right"><button ng-click="addLead()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save Lead</button></div>
</ng-form>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.addLead = function() {
        console.log($scope.add_lead_form);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Whta data do you want to pass? The entire form?

Comment: Why not `document.getElementsByName("add_lead_form")[0]` ?

Comment: Ideally, I'd be processing the entire form so I am looking to access each individual set of value/label.

Answer (score 1):

[**You could not access form inside `ng-repeat`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044600/2435473) which has been declared in parent div, For creating proper form you could add new `innerForm` inside your `ng-repeat`, You must need to change your html structure by adding new `innerForm`

```
<div ng-repeat="label in form.lead_labels track by $index" ng-show="label.visible">
    <ng-form name="innerForm">
        <div class="input-group lead-data">
            <span class="input-group-addon">{{getLabel(label)}}</span>
            <input ng-model="add_lead_form.addleadValue[$index]" name="innerForm.addleadValue" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="add_lead_form.addleadLabelId[$index]" name="innerForm.addleadLabelId" ng-value="label.id" />
        </div>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

Give a try by using above code, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This still results in a blank object for me. How would you reference it in your js?

Comment: @DonBoots could you please create a fiddle or plunkr?