# Angular dynamically set ng-messages to name attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I dynamically create inputs and want also validate every one of them but can't set correctly the `ng-messages` attribute to the field name property which is dynamically generated.

```
<input ng-model="sub.name" name="subName{{$index}}" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required maxlength="20" />
<div class="field-error" ng-messages="form.subName{{$index}}.$error" ng-show="form.Name.$touched" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Name is required.</div>
</div>
```

I got problem with second line where I set the `ng-messages` dynamically to `ng-messages`. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes i got error, i cant send the ng-messages attribute with {{}} syntax, "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 13 of the expression [form.subName{{index}}.$error] starting at [{{index}}.$error]"

Comment: thats pretty weird cause i can set this on name attribute on input but can't on ng-messages :/

Comment: this piece of code is inside an ng-repeat??

Comment: yes its inside ng-repeat

Comment: this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044277/how-to-validate-inputs-dynamically-created-using-ng-repeat-ng-show-angular

Answer (score 57):

Accessing the properties of your form object can also be done using brackets, which should solve your problem :

```
<input ng-model="sub.name" name="subName{{$index}}" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required maxlength="20" />
<div class="field-error" ng-messages="form['subName' + $index].$error" ng-show="form.Name.$touched" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Name is required.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, was having the same issue and it worked for me. Can you explain more on why form[] exists?

Comment: "form" is the name on the form so <form name="form"...> you could also do <form name="myForm"...> and the ng-messages directive would look like this ng-message="myForm['subName'...]. This works and should be the accepted answer

Comment: This code only works for me when I changed ng-show="form.Name.$touched" to ng-show="form['subName' + $index].$touched"

Comment: Thanks this information really helped me, was using ng-messages but my input field had a name in the format "firstpart.secondpart" which angular couldnt understand.  However using form['firstpart.secondpart'].$error fixed the problem.  Thanks.