# Validating dynamic forms using ng-messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I'm trying to create a bunch of reusable components, which are mainly form controls.

For this reason, I believe  (Maybe there is a different approach for this?) I need to create dynamic names for the `ng-form` directive so that it won't overwrite another `ng-form` in the same scope.

The problem is that I'm not able do validation since expressions aren't working with `ng-messages`.

Below is a very simplified demo (*sorry about the long template string, couldn't find a better way to add it in stacksnippets*), with just one instance of directive and no other parent scopes. But in real scenario those will be there, so I'm creating form name dynamically.

```js
angular.module('test', ['ngMessages'])
  .directive('formGroup', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        classList: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class=\"container\" ng-class=\"classList\" ng-form=\"fg_{{$id}}\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"testInput\" ng-model=\"testValue\"  required><div ng-messages=\"fg_$id.$error\"><p ng-message=\"required\">Something is wrong!<\/p><\/div><\/div>'
    }
  });
```

```css
div.container {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <form-group classList="sample-class"></form-group>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm creating the form name using the scopes `$id` with a prefix `fg_`. But it doesn't work like `ng-messages="fg_$id.$error"` and `ng-messages="fg_{{$id}}.$error"` throws error.

What is the proper way to do this, or if not, how can we get around it?

---

P.S: I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31456539/2333214), a few similar ones and articles, but none of them answers this simple scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this['fg_' + $id].$error` as parameter to `ngMessages` directive.

You can find working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v4qdhe9f/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('test', ['ngMessages'])
  .directive('formGroup', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        classList: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class=\"container\" ng-class=\"classList\" ng-form=\"fg_{{$id}}\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"testInput\" ng-model=\"testValue\"  required><div ng-messages=\"this[\'fg_\' + $id].$error\"><p ng-message=\"required\">Something is wrong!<\/p><\/div><\/div>'
    }
  });
```

```css
div.container {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <form-group classList="sample-class"></form-group>
</div>
```