# How to add ng-messages to a dynamically created input in AngularJS with Material

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the following code that works except for the part where I try to add the ng-messages (they don't display).  From my understanding, the ng-messages attaches to the name element.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
<form ng-submit="submit(form)" name="form">
   <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <div ng-switch="question.type">
         <div ng-switch-when="text">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
               <label>{{question.title}}</label>
               <input md-maxlength={{question.maxLength}}
                      required md-no-asterisk
                      name="questionStorage[question.id]"
                      ng-model="questionStorage[question.id]">
               <div ng-messages="form[questionStorage[question.id]].$error">
                   <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
...
```

Comment: I would not use an editable model value for that. I'd recommend something like setting the `name` of your `<input>` to `question_$index` and then using `form.question_$index.$error` for your `ng-messages`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Lex and [Angular dynamically set ng-messages to name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456539/angular-dynamically-set-ng-messages-to-name-attribute)
I found the answer to be:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(form)" name="form">
   <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <div ng-switch="question.type">
         <div ng-switch-when="text">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
               <label>{{question.title}}</label>
               <input md-maxlength={{question.maxLength}}
                      required md-no-asterisk
                      name="question{{$index}}"
                      ng-model="questionStorage[question.id]">
               <div ng-messages="form['question' + $index].$error">
                   <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
...
```

Thanks!